# Socket io establishes 2 connection by the time i run the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

The problem with this simple app is that it establishes 2 connections from the moment i run the nodejs program on terminal. That means that before requesting for the page at port 5555 on the browser, the program creates 2 connections with 2 different ids

server side

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 5555 || process.env.PORT;
const http = require('http')
const options = {};
const cookie = require('cookie');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server,options);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'views')));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
let counter =0;
io.on('connection', socket =>{
    counter++;
    socket.on('private message', (anotherSocketId,msg)=>{
        socket.to(anotherSocketId).emit('private message',socket.id,msg);
    });

    console.log(`server socket id ${counter} : ${socket.id}`);
    console.log(`server client : ${socket.client}`);
    // console.log(`server ip of client : ${cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie)}`);
});
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index2');
})
server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`listening on port : ${port}`);
})
```

console message  :

```
listening on port : 5555
server socket id 1 : snUlVUeYMoHL_6tuAAAB
server client : [object Object]
server socket id 2 : TLq1SFQ90H7VbMnbAAAD
server client : [object Object]
```

idk if it matters but i also have this code on the client side

```
const socket = io();
        
        socket.on('connect',()=>{
            console.log(`client socket id : ${socket.id}`)
        })
```

Comment: When you start the server, is the front end tab opened already?

Comment: yes that was it

Answer (score -1):

haHAA i am a lil bit dumb . i just realised that i had already opened 2 localhost:5555 tabs on the browser so i suppose from the moment that the server starts running a connection is established to every opened tab despite being refreshed or not